# Keep count of occurrences in a truncating file

Tags: bash, grep, counter, cat, wc

Let's say I have a file called *data.log*.

Data constantly gets appended to it which can contain '*flag*' and it gets truncated by an external script:

> [13/Jan/2015:11:11:53 +0000] curabitur **flag** lacinia nibh in feugiat mollis
>
> tail: data.log: file truncated
>
> [13/Jan/2015:11:11:53 +0000] dapibus enim sagittis efficitur
>
> [13/Jan/2015:11:11:54 +0000] iaculis non **flag** ac urna.

After declaring `counter=0`, I want to increment it with the amount of found occurrences. I came up with something like this, which uses `wc -l` to count the lines in *data.log* containing '*flag*':

```
counter=$(($counter+$(cat data.log | grep s | wc -l)))
echo $counter
```

Now there's only one problem left: the truncating. How would I approach this? I thought of doing a [`watch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch), but how do I pick up on the truncating event? Or is there another direction I should be heading altogether?

Comment: As an aside, `$(cat data.log)` can be done purely in `bash` as: `$(< data.log)` which is a bit more efficient. Also, `counter=$(($counter+3))` can be written as: `((counter += 3))` (which is a bit easier to read IMO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$ tail -F data.log | grep --line-buffered s | while read match ; do ((counter++)) ; done
```

The `-F` flag for `tail` is the same as `--follow --retry`. `--retry` is the magic bit here:

```
   --retry
          keep trying to open a file even when it is or becomes inaccessi‐
          ble; useful when following by name, i.e., with --follow=name
```

I also used `--line-buffered` with `grep`, to avoid the while loop needing to wait for output.

One problem with this that I've just realised: if *flag* appears more than once for every line, `$counter` will still only be incremented by 1. But that issue is in your solution as well.

Comment: Awesome. Great solution and looks nice too. Thanks a lot!